# Distribution failed with XCode 10 beta 4 - [ERROR ITMS-90534]

Tags: ios, testflight, app-store-connect

I tried to distribute my app to AppStore Connect with organizer "Distribute App" button.

Upload failed with theses errors. First error and warning are okay.

But the second error isn't cool..

[image: distribution failed XCode 10]

We can't distribute app build from XCode beta ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

At some point, Apple will release a GM version of Xcode 10 and you will get an email saying you can now submit your builds. Until then, Xcode beta is solely for development/testing, and not distribution.

Comment: Is this still true? Cannot find any documentation proving or disproving this.